# Create webpage in PHP using netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans, xampp

I am using netbeans to create a php project with XAMPP using linux but i am not able to set the path to my File System for htdocs folder.How can I do that because there is no File System option when I browse.

Comment: Which path are you trying to set? The project path? The upload path? Please explain all of the steps you have performed to get to where you are stuck.

Comment: @RobertB- The path that I have used is home/nespl/opt/lampp/htdocs/demo.php. But I want to save my php folder in opt folder which is in File System but I am unable to do that.I am new in PHP.

Comment: I don't really need to know the specific path. Instead I need to know exactly what you are trying to do on the Netbeans side. It is not clear from your question. Edit your question to provide more details. Are you trying to set the project path? Are you trying to copy built files by FTP?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using NetBeans' built in feature to copy your sources to the htdocs upon save - this way you have a "web-ready" copy of your project files running locally in xampp.  This also gives you a little flexibility if you are syncing/automatic backup (so you can backup your sources without having to keep a copy of your whole web directory).

1. Open your project in NetBeans
2. File -> Project Properties
3. Choose "Sources" as the category
4. Check:  "Copy files from Sources Folder to another location
5. Copy to Folder: (make this your htdocs directory)
6. Check: "Copy files on project open"
7. Click "OK"